# Entity Framework 6 says two entries have the same primary key, while they are in completely different tables

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent, table-per-class

**Edit 1:** So I wasn't getting anywhere and tried something different. I renamed my FriendRequest class to FriendRequestBase and made it abstract and then I made a FriendRequest class that inherits from FriendRequestBase without any extra fields, so now the inheritance looks like this:
FriendRequest : FriendRequestBase
GroupModRequest : FriendRequestBase

That should work, right? Well now, I added a migration to see if it will add any changes and yes, for some reason it now starts dropping foreign keys.

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.GroupModRequests", "SenderID", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
DropForeignKey("dbo.GroupModRequests", "ReceiverID", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
```

What could be the problem there? I've correctly set up the foreign keys with the Fluent API:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupModRequest>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Receiver)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.ReceiverID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupModRequest>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Sender)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.SenderID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupModRequest>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Group)
            .WithMany(g => g.GroupModRequests)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.GroupID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I'm trying to seed my database after running 'update-database' and this is what I'm getting:

> All objects in the EntitySet 'ApplicationDbContext.FriendRequests'
>   must have unique primary keys. However, an instance of type
>   'AW.Models.GroupModRequest' and an instance of type
>   'AW.Models.FriendRequest' both have the same primary key value,
>   'EntitySet=FriendRequests;SenderID=a9540bd6-8532-4c7a-9f68-19d2aeecffcb;ReceiverID=8f50eccf-8ccf-432e-a033-82d933b5e3f5'.

As I mentioned previously, FriendRequests are in one table and GroupModRequests are in a different table so this error doesn't make sense. *I can kind of guess why this happens, though.*

GroupModRequests inherits from FriendRequests and I'm using the Table-Per-Conrete-Class approach, meaning that FriendRequests has a table and GroupModRequests has a table and it has all of the properties FriendRequests have plus some more. Note, that FriendRequests isn't an abstract class.

**FriendRequests** has a composite primary key consisting of: *SenderID, ReceiverID*.
**GroupModRequests** has a composite primary key consisting of: *SenderID, ReceiverID and GroupID*.

And so I bet that for some reason it is ignoring the 'GroupID' part of the key and ignoring the fact that they are in different tables and throws this error when a FriendRequest has the same Sender/Receiver ID as a GroupModRequest.

So how can I fix this in EF6? I already set this with fluent, but apparently that isn't enough:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupModRequest>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("GroupModRequests");
            });
```

The composite keys look like this:

```
 public class FriendRequest
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string SenderID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SenderID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Sender { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ReceiverID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReceiverID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Receiver { get; set; }
}

public class GroupModRequest : FriendRequest
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public Guid GroupID { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

}
```

**Note:** I also have 'LocationModRequests' which inherits from FriendRequests as well and is almost the same as GroupModRequests, if it matters.

Comment: You are inheriting the table so all feilds will be inherited so the key is also being inherited.

Comment: Yea well, how do I stop it from inheriting the key, then?

Comment: Make it virtual. And in GroupModRequest make the key as Composite Key.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, could you elaborate? Make what virtual? And I already have the key as a composite key (I have [Key, Column(Order = X)] above each part of the key)

Comment: Make SenderID  virtual in FriendRequest.

Comment: What would that do? And I suppose you mean ReceiverID as well.

Comment: Than you will not get that error.

Comment: Well it didn't work - now it thinks that multiple entities in the same table have the same Primary Key (I checked - they dont)